# Less: @import url using http instead of https after minification

Tags: css, angularjs, fonts, less, minify

I am getting this error:

`Mixed Content: The page at 'https://theculprit.com/url' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure font 'http://fonts.gstatic.com/s/opensans/v10/DXI1ORHCpsQm3Vp6mXoaTYnF5uFdDttMLvmWuJdhhgs.ttf'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.`

When I looked through the source to find where the font was being imported via HTTP rather than HTTPS, the only line pertaining to a font import was:

```
@import url('//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,700,300,600,800');
```

Initially I though [HTTPS assets loading over HTTP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28161800/https-assets-loading-over-http) could be my error, but the font is already being imported using the sources protocol. This only happens after the code has been minified.

I'm not very familiar with fonts/css/less, so I'm completely lost. If there is any other info I can give to help out let me know.

Comment: Are you sure your import is coming across as https? The URL causing the issue is coming from the CSS you are importing, not the line of JS. https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,700,300,600,800

Comment: @MatthewGreen I'm under the assumption that starting an import with '//myurl' automatically makes the request with the protocol of the source of the call. Is that incorrect? I know that the line of JS is not what is causing the error, I just listed it as another bit of information.

Comment: It should work that way. You can see that when you hit the font.googleapis URL that the protocol changes for the links in that CSS based on what you use. However, that clearly isn't working in this case. I would try using a protocol to see if the error goes away and then see if maybe your CSS import is actually using the wrong protocol.

Comment: @MatthewGreen So when I changed that import line to use the https protocol I saw the gstatic url change from http to https. My question now is that how come if I hit the fonts.googleapis link directly from my browser, I don't see the gstatic URL in the network activity at all - nothing gets downloaded. Is that font import running on the actual site the source of the fonts.gstatic call?

Comment: It should only download something if it needs that resource. So you have to be using it in your CSS and not already have a local copy of that font on your computer for it to download. So just hitting the URL in the browser isn't a good test for that.

Comment: @MatthewGreen Just found out that if I use unminified CSS everything works as expected (using just //fonts.googleapis). Any ideas as to what might be happening during minification that would cause it to use http?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71345/discussion-between-aaron-and-matthew-green).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turns out the [minifier](https://github.com/jakubpawlowicz/clean-css) I am using [automatically](https://github.com/jakubpawlowicz/clean-css/blob/master/lib/imports/inliner.js#L219) turns an import starting with `//myurl` to `http://myurl` and that was causing my issue. I added the `processImport: false` [option](https://github.com/jakubpawlowicz/clean-css#how-to-use-clean-css-programmatically) and now everything is working as intended.

An issue has been opened regarding this behavior on [GitHub](https://github.com/jakubpawlowicz/clean-css/issues/448).

Answer (score 1):

If you are hosting a site on https then you are going to run into trouble importing external files using http protocol.

I recommend you download the google font and host it on site itself.

or another option.

You can use webfonts without importing external files. You can include the fonts directly into your css file using data uri. First you will need to download the google font.

Convert the files to a data string ([dataurlmaker](http://dataurl.net/#dataurlmaker))

Create your @font-face eg.

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'MyWebFont';
  src: url('webfont.eot'); /* IE9 Compat Modes */
  src: url('webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
       url('webfont.woff2') format('woff2'),
       url('webfont.woff') format('woff'),
       url('webfont.ttf')  format('truetype'),
       url('webfont.svg#svgFontName') format('svg');
}
```

And replace your urls with the data values

Answer (score 0):

I was facing same problem. But I didn't wanted to use @Aaron's solution as that way any of my @import won't work.
A better alternative may be :

```
{processImportFrom: ['!fonts.googleapis.com']}
```

So like in my case gulp was changing fonts.googleapis.com to http://fonts.gstatic.com now as my site was on https chrome was giving error. "blacklisting" this using the above option worked for me. Though I think there must be other options out there, like, option to add https imports.